# compare two dictionaries in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I have two dictionaries

```
old = { C43: 'X13',
  C59: 'X13',
  C75: 'X14',
  C91: 'X14',
  C107: 'X16',
  C123: 'X17' }
```

The ```old`` can have any number of entries.

and

```
new = { C139: 'X17' }
```

The ```new`` can have any number of entries.

I am trying to match the values of both dictionaries and move the `keys` from `old` wherever the values in `old` and `new` match.

The output to be in a new array as,

```
new_array = [ C123 ]
```

I tried the below, but I am not doing it right, Please guide

```
var new_array = [];
        for (var key in old) {
          var check_matching_value = old[key] === new[key]
          if (check_matching_value == true) {
            new_array.push(key);
          }
        }
        console.log(matchingKeys);
```

Comment: instead of  checking twice with matching_Value.
Try this
`for (var key in old) {
  if (old[key] in new) {
    new_array.push(key);
  }`

Comment: Thank you @Samuel, This did not work, my new_array is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter()`, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const oldDict = {
    C43: 'X13',
    C59: 'X13',
    C75: 'X14',
    C91: 'X14',
    C107: 'X16',
    C123: 'X17',
  };
  const newDict = { C139: 'X17', };
  const newValues = Object.values(newDict);
  const newArray = Object.keys(oldDict)
    .filter(key => newValues.includes(oldDict[key]));
  console.log(newArray); // "C123"
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @doubleunary, this is very helpful. I shall try with different variations